# Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object in api call

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webapi

I have an api `response` which I want to convert into Datatable, so for that I write the below code.

```
inputJsonIPColoMaster = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(inputIPColoMaster);

                                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                                client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                                json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJsonIPColoMaster);
                                DataTable dtRes = new DataTable();
                                
                                StringReader sr = new StringReader(json);
                                dtRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json); // here is the error
```

So while DeSerializing it I am getting error as.

> Additional text found in JSON string....

Below is my response.

```
{"Status":"Failed","Code":"400","Message":"Request initiation failed"}
```

Comment: It's a http 400 error because your request isn't being processed. There is something wrong with your request.

Comment: @PeterDongan: whatever the code be, I want to print that response in Datatable..

Comment: I think it needs to be in a collection.

Comment: can u help me with that collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to show the response on a data grid view, here is how you can achieve it:

(P.S: I have seen your other question as well - [Assign var values in a datatable c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127953/assign-var-values-in-a-datatable-c-sharp))

```
var list = new List<ApiResponseModel>();
var json = "{\"Status\":\"Failed\",\"Code\":400,\"Message\":\"Request initiation failed\"}";
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseModel>(json);
model.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); //set NEID
list.Add(model);

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

ApiResponseModel.cs

```
public class ApiResponseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will check in sometime and update you.. also what should I do to bring NEID

Comment: Could you explain what is NEID?

Comment: It’s one of the unique value which I need to bring to identify the json values..

Comment: You can add another property in your model and assign it after deserialization. Refer to the updated answer :)

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly. Just one more thing, I need to check if `list` is blank or not, and also insert the data into the table

Comment: Right now the datagridview is binded to the list, if the list is empty, your datagridview will be empty. If you need to check whether the list contains any elements, you can do list.Any() and check if it is true. What do you mean by “also insert the data into the table”? Do you need a DataTable object?